# SQL: Clause LIKE work incorrect with variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS SQL Server:

first sql:

```
select id, scope from delivery 
where scope like '%bunkering%'
order by scope desc
```

As result return **34** rows and in column scope I get ONLY text **bunkering**.

Nice. It's correct.

Now I want to use variable, like this:

```
DECLARE @SCOPE varchar = '%bunkering%'
select id, scope from delivery 
where scope like @SCOPE 
order by scope desc
```

But now I get **38** rows. And now has rows not only with text **bunkering**.
Also has text "**mecanisme port**"

Why?
I need only text **bunkering**.
How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

error persist here

> DECLARE @SCOPE varchar = '%bunkering%'

please mention the length of varchar datatype

use

```
DECLARE @SCOPE varchar(50) = '%bunkering%'
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a length for the variable declaration:

```
DECLARE @SCOPE varchar(255) = '%bunkering%';

select id, scope
from delivery 
where scope like @SCOPE 
order by scope desc;
```

When declaring a variable, `varchar` with no length defaults to a length of 1.  So, you have set the variable `@SCOPE` to `'%'`, which should match all rows.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
DECLARE @SCOPE varchar = 'bunkering'
select id, scope from delivery 
where scope like '%' + @SCOPE + '%' 
order by scope desc
```

And it's work fine.

Comment: Would be interesting to see what @SCOPE is set to.